# pythonのプログラムでacces tokenのエラーについて

Tags: python, twitter

下記のプログラムを使って、pythonからweiboの投稿を取得したいです。

プログラムの内容

```
from weibo import APIClient    # suppose you are using Twitter

APP_KEY = '294703483'            # app key
APP_SECRET = 'a2ef9de0a580edb7a26daf2804d27624'      # app secret
CALLBACK_URL = 'https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/authorize'  # callback url

client = APIClient(app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET, redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL,
               access_token=2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE , expires=1635772406)

print client.statuses.user_timeline.get()
```

プログラム実行
エラーメッセージ

```
[root@localhost michaelliao-sinaweibopy-7b4408a]# python salsa.py
File "salsa.py", line 9
access_token=2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE , expires=1635772406)
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

pythonからsinaweibodyのプログラムについては[michaelliao](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO) /[sinaweibopy](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy)から情報を取得しました。

[ACCESTOKEN](http://blog.csdn.net/minenki/article/details/8836293)とexpiresはプログラムを実行して取得しました。
accestokenは[weiboguide](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/)でも取得できます。

input the code: e983face8da18b92e14397505b02882b
Successfully get access_token: 2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE
Successfully get expires_in: 1635771889
エラーが何故起きるかわかる方がいれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これは Access token のエラーではなくて [`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError) とあるとおり構文エラーです．

たとえば

```
>>> a = 1s
  File "<stdin>", line 1
  a = 1s
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

質問中のコードで言えば`access_token=2.00sk..` のところが問題で，本来文字列のところをクオートしそこねているのでしょう．

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。access_token='2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE'に変更してみましたら、下記のエラーが出ます。Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "salsa.py", line 9, in <module>
    access_token='2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE', expires=1635772406)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'access_token'

Comment: @FannyZhingre そうなると上とは別の質問になると思いますが，それは [`weibo.APIClient`](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/blob/e41e4fc68ea4cbb95a22fdce0eae97ee4eb9b723/weibo.py#L182-L197) には `access_token` を渡せないからです（`snspy.APIClient` にはあるようですが）．

Comment: ＠Yosh 承知いたしました。 ありがとうございました。

Comment: 上記コメント，途中で送信してしまってました（編集しました）．すみません．